# c++ http/2 parsing upgrade

Tags: c++, parsing, http2

I am currently using a C++ library to parse http messages from github: [http-parser](https://github.com/joyent/http-parser). However I want to make sure that it will also work with **http/2**.

I have started to read the [rfc for http/2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540) but I am not really sure where to start. From what I have read so far, there are no major differences parsing-wise for http/2, but I am not sure how to proceed further.

For example there is a section that describes **server-push** that is new to http/2. So, I'd have a manually check if the header contains PUSH_PROMISE. However, I am not sure this path would be healthy(manually treating the differences) and it would be nice if the library would treat these special cases for me.

Any advice on how to proceed?

Comment: Are you looking for a way to test your library?

Comment: Well, I will do testing too, with some http/2 servers, but the thing is I can't find a c++ http parser that is saying it's explicitly supporting http/2.

Comment: So you want a library recommendation? This is explicitly off topic here.

Comment: There's [a list of implementations of HTTP/2 on github](https://github.com/http2/http2-spec/wiki/Implementations). But I haven't used any, so I can't recommend one.

Answer (score 0):

not a direct replacement for http-parser, but [nghttp2](https://github.com/nghttp2/nghttp2) seems to be one of the reference implementations of http2 these days (both library and CLI).